# Water desalination

Tags: thermodynamics

If there was a device, black-box, that salinated water flows in and output is salt and de-salinated water? But de-salinated water is colder than input of salinated water. Is it technically possible?

Comment: Is the black box powered ?

Comment: Reverse osmosis exists, but the exiting streams are pure water and very salty water.  I don't know of any technology that can produce dry salt as a product stream without boiling salt water and condensing the water vapor, and this process is very energy intensive.

Comment: Thermal energy of black box output is lower than of black box input. Water can be boiled in black box, nobody knows.

Comment: Yes the process is energy intensive, but we have magic called thermal isolation and heat pump with Q of 5. Heat engine with Q of 0.3...

Comment: The black box could be a solar collector - only works with sun though ... goid in many countries.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible ?  Yes.
Is it efficient ?  It costs power, as any such process will.

The process you probably need is a vacuum freeze-thaw method of desalination developed by one [Alexander Zarchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Zarchin).

In essence you create a vacuum, spray water (as a vapor if I understand this correctly) and it freezes and this causes the salt and water separate.  You collect the ice (desalinated water) and salt separately.

This process can also be done without the vacuum (just freeze-thaw), but I would presume it's not as efficient or takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question, the black box is not "powered", i.e. there is only an input of salt water, an output of salt, and output of fresh water (colder than the input) and no other exchange of matter or energy.

Then the answer is: "no". Mixing dry salt and fresh water we get a solution, the salt water, which has less free energy: the process is spontaneous in isothermal conditions. The reverse requires the consumption of some free energy source. This energy is a free energy, thus it cannot be provided at the expense of the thermal content of the liquid itself.

Other curious things can be done with salt water and heat. For example, you can build a black box having an input of fresh water, an input of salt and an output of salt water, which is warm or cold, depending on the salt, and also an output of electric energy. See the pressure-retarded osmosis, reverse electrodialysis or capacitive mixing techniques.